# can we insert or from another linked list while traversing one LINKED LIST in c/C++

Tags: c++, linked-list

can we form another or insert the values in node of linked list while traversing in another linked list like we do in arrays. Don't know why but there are some errors upcoming in my code. Like it goes to infinity loop despite having correct logic and code to do that.
I have pasted important codes to look not whole code as it is long. I have already inserted the values and character in linkedlist pointed by head1, in my code.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
struct node
{
    char data1;
    int data2;
    node *link;
};
node *head1=NULL;
node *head=NULL;
void insert_at_end(char x,int y)
{
node *temp2=new node;
temp2->data1=x;
temp2->data2=y;
temp2->link=NULL;
if(head==NULL)
{head=temp2;}
else
{
node *temp3=head;
while(temp3->link!=NULL)
{
    temp3=temp3->link;
}
temp3->link=temp3;
}
}
//in main function//
node *temp7=head1;
    while(temp7!=NULL)
    {
        insert_at_end(temp7->data1,temp7->data2);
        if(temp7->data2==A[num])
        break;
        temp7=temp7->link;
    }
```

Comment: ***can we form another or insert the values in node of linked list while traversing in another linked list like we do in arrays.*** Yes of course that is possible.

Comment: ***Don't know why but there are some errors upcoming in my code*** Anytime you get in this situation your first thought should be to step through your code line by line in a debugger looking at the variables at each step to see how your code execution deviates from your expectation. And I mean step by step, not pressing a play looking button and praying that the debugger finds something for you (it most cases it won't). This requires that you spend 20 or so minutes to learn how to use the features of your debugger.

Comment: When there is a fault in your program your first thought should be that it is an error in your code. And 99 times out of 100 you will be right. This is true for experienced programmers, as it is for beginners. So don't be so sure that your logic is right, it almost certainly isn't. Assuming that the fault lies elsewhere just makes it harder to find your bugs.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use C++11, or newer, you can use the STL and make life easier. In your compiler options just add the text `-std=c++11`:

```
#include <list>

struct node
{
  char data1;
  int  data2;

  node() : data1(0), data2(0) {}
  node(char x, int y) : data1(x), data2(y) {}
};

std::list<node> myList;

void main()
{
  // Add something to the end - insert_at_end.
  myList.push_back(node('c', 42));

  // Look for items in the list.
  for(auto& item : myList)
  {
    if(item.data2 == A[num])
    {
       // Do something here if you found the item you're looking for.
    }
  }
}
```